# What exactly should we do to get bcache?

Tags: bcache

I am extremely confused about this bcache thingy here.

On one hand some says that it's already incorporated into linux kernel.

Then some says that I need to patch my linux kernel. If it's already incorporated, why do I have to patch the kernel?

From http://pommi.nethuis.nl/ssd-caching-using-linux-and-bcache/

and from http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/#Getting_bcache

> **Bcache has been merged into the mainline Linux kernel; for the latest stable bcache release use the latest 3.10 or 3.11 stable kernel**
>
> For the userspace tools:
>   git clone http://evilpiepirate.org/git/bcache-tools.git
>
> The udev rules, Debian/Ubuntu source package, and Ubuntu PPA are maintained here:
>   git clone https://github.com/g2p/bcache-tools.git
>
> To use the PPA (Ubuntu Raring and Saucy):
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:g2p/storage
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install bcache-tools
>
> The PPA also contains blocks, a conversion tool. A Fedora package is available in Fedora 20, and maintained here.

So basically it says that bcache is already released on 3.11 stable kernel. Then it follows "For the userspace tools, git clone bla bla bla"

What is userspace? What is git? If it's already on the kernel why do I have to do anything at all?

I want to install bcache on my typical centos webserver. This is what I found:

> > Hello,
> >
> > I would like to implement a solution with ssd caching Bcache on
> >     CentOS. Have you ever implemented a solution to this distribution
> >     (or kernel)? if so, do you have a package?
>
> There's no packages, it's not integrated with any distributions -
>   you've got to build your own kernel and tools.  Check the wiki for
>   more info.

What wiki? Do there's no package, it's not distributed, then got to build my own kernel. What does it mean? How do I build my own kernel?

Comment: On which distribution you want to install bcache?

Comment: centos. I want to install that on centos

Answer (score 2):

> What is userspace?

"[Userspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userspace) tools" would refer to utility applications.  For example, `fdisk` and the shell are userspace tools.  They both make use of *system calls* to get the kernel to do stuff for them.  As an analogy, the hardware drivers etc. which make fdisk possible are built into the kernel, but fdisk itself is not.  *ALL programs exist in userspace.* Userspace exists in contrast to kernel space, which is where the kernel operates.

I haven't used bcache, so I don't know if the userspace tools are essential or important.  If it can be configured and enabled via, e.g., a `/proc` interface, then they probably aren't absolutely necessary, but they may still make life easier.

> What is git?

[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) is a version control system (VCS).  For you purposes here, it's just a mechanism for downloading source code.  This means you'll have to compile the code on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat 6 and subsequently CentOS 6 are still on the 2.6.32 kernel so your distribution doesn't support Bcache yet.

The CentOs wiki has a pretty good article on howto build your own kernel from source http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel